# SSIS for VS2022 installation dialog box not showing the instances & Install button is also disabled

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022

After successfully installed VS 2022 using offline packages, trying to install SSIS for VS2022 which is downloaded from official site,  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.MicrosoftDataToolsIntegrationServices
. When tried to install this, the installation dialog box is not listing the installed instances from my machine due to this the 'Install' button also not enabled. I am stuck here, any advice please.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because SSIS is only uploading to 2019, I recommend to install the 2019 version.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).